# How to install Google Music on a non-US phone?

Tags: google-play-store

I am trying to install Google Music on my phone from outside the US. After using Market Enabler Play Store correctly displays and even downloads the app, but then aborts with "this app cannot be installed in your country". It still doesn't work after rebooting my phone. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no trouble getting it myself, but that was a while ago.  Have you tried using a US proxy or [sideloading the app](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/16/updated-google-music-4-0-9-app-now-live-on-the-android-market/)?  Another option would be to switch to data or Wi-Fi for the download, whichever you weren't using, to see if it's just the particular network that the Play Store has a problem with.

Comment: Any idea which of the direct download links is legit? I don't recognize the sites, and I don't want malware.

Comment: @ripper234 Android Police uploads to the sites, it doesn't post unverified links from other sources.

Comment: Both links in that article are now 404 (removed due to copyright)

Comment: Please reopen my question - it is not an exact dup. I'm not asking about the technical "how to", but just where can I find a trusted apk. This question does not contain this information.

Comment: @ripper234 This answer contains a link to a post with an .apk that I trust. We don't handle questions that only ask for shopping help or links, so this "how to" is the closest you'll get. And this isn't the place to discuss your other question.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this has been marked as answered, but I wish to add this:

Most apps like that tell which country your from from your locale setting. This can be changed from the settings menu, or using the app locale switcher.

Comment: Seriously? What about those who live in a "foreign" (relative to them) country but still want to use their phone in the mother tongue?

Comment: Where in the Setings menu? (For Samsung S2 with Android 4.0.3)

Comment: @ripper234 Language and Input. But it doesn't work, you need something like market enabler.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I believe that the Play Store determines the country with help of the SIM card.